# iOS which thread NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest runs on

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue, networkonmainthread

I am using following code to make a network call. I know the response will be run in mainQueue as I have specified queue parameter as `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` but I am wondering where would actual `sendAsynchronousRequest` operation will be performed. The operation is called from mainThread so would that run asynchronously on the main thread or `NSURLConnection` creates background thread automatically? There is no documentation for this and iOS instrument doesn't show background threads detached so wondering how exactly this works! Apple document doesn't give details about this.

BTW I know this is deprecated but we have legacy code yet to migrate to use `NSURLSession`

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if(completion) {
                               completion(data, error);
                           }
                       }];
```

Same issue when you use following version;

```
self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

Here also not sure which thread this request executes on and how to make this run asynchronously!

Comment: is it causing you a problem or you're just curious?

Comment: It's not causing any issues but I want to make sure operation must not run on main thread and should be detached on other thread. I do not want to dispatch on background thread unless absolutely required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` uses its own internal queue. It now is a wrapper around `NSURLSession`, and you can find the queue (if you're interested) by looking for `com.apple.NSURLSession-work` in your thread list.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Would that run on background thread or main thread?

Comment: An internal queue is by definition not the main queue. And only the main queue runs on the main thread.